# Delete hung firefox update?

Tags: macos, firefox, updates

Firefox displays the following message when I open it:

[image: Firefox Software Update Failed]

Firefox also provides this:

[image]

The problem began last week or the week before. When it happened, I manually installed the latest version.

Even though I am running the latest Firefox, I can't get the message to go away.

[How to fix the Update Failed error message when updating Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/update-failed-error-message-when-updating) did not help. And deleting `/Library/Caches/` and `~/Library/Caches/` did not help.

How do I resolve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/all the latest version of Firefox for OSX is v32. You might want to get the latest version. That is probably why it is suggesting that you update.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it. When I had the problem, I performed a manual download and install; but the problem remained. I have not gotten any bulletins regarding updates since I last updated, so I believe I already have the latest.

Comment: Your screenshot says v31 is why I doubt that. Unless this screen shot is from the last version?